# bootstrap 4 inline text next to the brand

Tags: bootstrap-4

How do I get navbar text next to the brand in one line?? 
I have test page at http://zeroplanet.gq/test.html where is text ,,Hello, Admin", but this text is not inline.

Here is code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="nav-item">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand text-white">
        <img src="#" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        <b>Zero</b>Planet </a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-light mr-auto">Welcome, Admin</div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link text-white">Test</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link text-white">Test</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link text-white">Error page</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link text-white">Account</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark border border-white">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

EDIT: I found if I try remove div with class="collapse navbar-collapse" the text is inline, but i need this div for mobile toogle..
Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collapse div class is too large when its not collapsed.

You can try use the "**max-width**" css property at this line:

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">`

or a "**min-width**" here:

`<div class="text-light mr-auto">Welcome, Admin</div>`